# Git command when translating files in Django

Tags: python, django, translation

I have an existing application in Django.
I want to add a translation on the page.
On page I have:

```
{% trans 'Projects'%}
```

In .po file I added:

```
#: templates/staff/site.html: 200
msgid "Projects"
msgid "Projekty"
```

Then executes the command:

```
django-admin.py compilemessages -l pl
```

After this command, I get an error:

```
CommandError: This Should Be Run script from the Django Git checkout or your project or app tree, or with the settings Specified module.
```

Comment: This error message is a bit misleading. You have to run django-admin commands from the root directory of your project, the one with `manage.py` inside. `cd` there and then run your command once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error holds the answer, you could be running the script from *anywhere* so it cannot know which files to compile. Run the command from the project directory or specify the settings and you should be fine.

Comment: how does one specify the settings?

Answer (score 22):

> $ python manage.py compilemessages --settings nsp.settings
>
> CommandError: This script should be run from the Django Git checkout or your project or app tree, or with the settings module specified.

I have got this error while I truly was inside project root folder.
The problem was, that I was running this command without `python manage.py makemessages` first.

The error message is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that it could not find the translations files where it expected them to be. Check that everything is correctly setup:

- `LOCALE_PATHS` is defined in your settings.py
- the files exist in the folder defined above (created by running `python manage.py makemessages`)

  - actually the error goes away even with just an empty locales folder
- the `compilemessages` command is run from the project root folder

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker containers to build and deploy your application you should copy folder:

`conf/`

from root folder of your django project.
with the conf folder you should see i.e:

```
processing file django.po in /gamma/conf/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
processing file django.po in /gamma/conf/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
processing file django.po in /gamma/conf/locale/pt_BR/
```

without the conf folder you should see a clueless message like that:

```
CommandError: This script should be run from the Django Git checkout or your project or app tree, or with the settings module specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't set [`LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#locale-paths) in your settings file, you need to do so:

```
import os
LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')]
```