# Django doesn`t create locale files

Tags: python, django

I'm new at Django and can't solve the problem. I wanna realize multi-language on my django project but when I type django-admin makemessages -l ru, Django doesn`t create locale folder with files in it. I did everything according to the documentation. Maybe my English is bad.
This is my settings

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGES = [
  ('ru', _('Russian')),
  ('uz', _('Uzbek')),
]
```

This is views.py file

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def index(request):
    phone = _('Welcome')
    return HttpResponse(phone)
```

But in header.html (layout file) django translate one word, "Home" to "Начало"

```
<li><a href="{% url 'index' %}" style="font-size: 18px;">{% trans "Home" %}</a></li>
```

[image]

Thank you a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git command when translating files in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027242/git-command-when-translating-files-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took my laptop and tried it on it, it worked.
Most likely this is due to the gettext file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I created five folders. After use command

```
    django-admin makemessages -a

/locale
       /en
          /LC_MESSAGES
       /es
          /LC_MESSAGES
```